# SQL statement that would reorganize results in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Region,Contact
  FROM Salesman_Info
Order by Region DESC;
```

The above query that I wrote does not execute results in order that is requested, as displayed in the attached image.

I'm new to SQL.

[image: Solution printout]

Comment: Sample data from `Salesman_Info` table?

Comment: I do not see any order sequence in your "Solution printout". Can you explain what order it should be?

Comment: what's the exact logic for the Region's ordering ..? Do you mean an alphabetical ordering with regions having more words ordered at last.

Comment: What method are you using to determine that order? Certainly it's not alphabetical (`'C'` is after both `'D'` and`'J'`). If it's the order of insertion, unless you have some kind of `SEQUENCE` or `IDENTITY` column, that "order" is lost as soon as you `INSERT` the data. A table has no "default" order; data is simply returned by the data engine in whatever order it feels like/finds first.

Comment: @PawelCz it the  Region should execute  Durban,John Durban,Mary Then Johannesburg,Frank then Cape Town - Anna Then Cape Town - Fred Then Cape Town - Joe

Comment: @NigelGovender is there any logic for ordering `Region`? Or it should be just print out without any logic in such order?

Comment: Currently its outputting Johannesburg - Frank first  using SELECT Region, Contact
  FROM Salesman_Info
Order by Region DESC, Contact;

Comment: Please add your question clarifications by way of an edit - this is presently missing an [mcve], and thus may be put on hold.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Below will give output you need, used @Barbaros (+1) suggestion.

```
declare @t table (region nvarchar(20), contact nvarchar(10))

insert into @t values 
('Cape Town','Anna'),
('Cape Town','Fred'),
('Durban','John'),
('Durban','Mary'),
('Johannesburg','Frank'),
('Cape Town','Joe')


select *       
from @t
order by charindex(' ',region) ,region asc, 
    contact asc;
```

Result

```
region          contact
Durban          John
Durban          Mary
Johannesburg    Frank
Cape Town       Anna
Cape Town       Fred
Cape Town       Joe
```

Comment: @NigelGovender, happy it worked for you, please upvote and accept answer then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
with t(region) as
(
 select 'Durban' union all    
 select 'Johannesburg' union all
 select 'Cape Town' 
)
select t.*       
  from t
 order by charindex(' ',region) , region;
```

if you region column's order is alphabetical with an exception of being composed of more than one word should be ordered at the last.

Answer (score 0):

May be just one more sorting field in the sort by clause?

```
SELECT Region, Contact
  FROM Salesman_Info
Order by Region DESC, Contact;
```

Comment: Doesnt give me the order. There are also no indexes or primary keys on table. Its a simple table I created with the values and need them outputted in format as per attachment please